# How can I filter rows by value and then count and plot pie chart and histogram?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

My data look like this:

```
{
    "raw_data": [
        {
            "agebracket": "",
            "currentstatus": "Hospitalized",
            "dateannounced": "05/06/2020",
            "gender": "",
            ....
        },
        {
            "agebracket": "",
            "currentstatus": "Recovered",
            "dateannounced": "05/06/2020",
            "gender": "",
            .........
        },
        {
            "agebracket": "",
            "currentstatus": "Hospitalized",
            "dateannounced": "05/06/2020",
            "gender": "",
            .......
        },
```

I am able to plot dc graph for the whole dataset. But now I want to filter it by `"currentstatus"` --> `"Recovered", "Hospitalized", "Deceased".`

Right now it looks like this:
https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/3699d4c0efb0ac1d81636cf0e05eda2d

I am trying to integrate it with https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/fbbae54c3f4d8b2df8f9b981d46857b4.

When I will click on confirmed box then pie and histogram will show results related to hospitalized. In that above (dashboard) Those three graphs didn't have to cross filter, So I was able to write the logic. But I am confused about this one. How should I go about filtering it by `"currentstatus" ("Hospitalized, "Recovered" etc)`

I want this to take a "currentstatus" variable and return results related to it.

```
var group = dim.group(function(d) { 
    return binwidth * Math.floor(d/binwidth); });
```

So that I can do :

```
    barChart
        .height(300)
        .width(500) //give it a width
        .dimension(dim)
        .group(group, currentstatus) //<------------------ Here
           .......
```

I am thinking about creating three arrays for Hospitalized, Recovered, and Deceased  Resp. But I think there might be some shorter solution than going this lengthy way.

### EDIT:

I tried that too but I don't know how to count.

The result should be(calculated using pandas) :

```
gender  currentstatus
F       Deceased           31
        Hospitalized     4225
        Recovered          33
M       Deceased           60
        Hospitalized     7570
        Recovered          50
```

But I get this:

```
0:
key: "M"
value: {Hospitalized: 7549, Deceased: 51, Recovered: 13}
__proto__: Object
1: {key: "NA", value: {…}}
2:
key: "F"
value: {Hospitalized: 4200, Deceased: 25, Recovered: 7}
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How do I count? I know this below logic is wrong:

```
var group1 = pieTypeDimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.currentstatus] = (p[v.currentstatus] || 0) + 1;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.currentstatus] -= 1;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
    });

log("group1:::", group1.top(Infinity));
```

Tried this too:

```
var group1 = pieTypeDimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        ++p.count;
        log("count:::", p.count);
        p[v.currentstatus] = (p[v.currentstatus] || 0) + p.count;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        --p.count;
        p[v.currentstatus] -= p.count;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // initial
        return {count:0};
    });
```

and get this:

```
0:
key: "M"
value:
count: 7613
Hospitalized: 28769566
Deceased: 173237
Recovered: 39888
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
1:
key: "NA"
value: {count: 3, Hospitalized: 6}
__proto__: Object
2:
key: "F"
value: {count: 4232, Hospitalized: 8903341, Deceased: 43001, Recovered: 10686}
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

## Edit:

I didn't take account of age bracket thing. Considering that Now it matches with the dc.js solution. So that logic is correct.

```
gender  currentstatus
F       Deceased           25
        Hospitalized     4200
        Recovered           7
M       Deceased           51
        Hospitalized     7549
        Recovered          13
Name: currentstatus, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer in a way that works with filtering, because that's the primary use case for dc.js.

I'd suggest going with the idiomatic crossfilter reduction for stacked charts, just without actually stacking anything.

[From the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#reducing-rows-that-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row):

```
var group = dimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.type] -= v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
    });
```

where `type` in your case is `currentstatus`.

This will give you a group where the values are objects keyed on status.

If you have every status for every X value, then each value object will have all status as keys; if not, some will be undefined.

Use `valueAccessor` to pull the field that you want for your chart, defaulting to 0 if undefined:

```
chart.valueAccessor(kv => kv.value[currentstatus] || 0)
```

Comment: I checked that solution but the things is I don't know how to count them after grouping them by gender. I have edited my post.